# Why is my code throwing a binary operator error on the second + sign for the counterLabel.text variable?

Tags: xcode, swift, binary-operators

This code throws the error "Binary Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Double'" on the second + sign of the counter Label.text variable. It only places the error here if I delete everything after the minutesLabel in counter Label.text the error goes away (This is written in Swift). Also sorry for any formatting confusion I'm a first time user.

```
func updateCounter(timer: NSTimer) {

        let hours = floor(stopWatchTime / pow(60, 2))
        let hoursInSeconds = hours * pow(60, 2)

        let minutes = floor((stopWatchTime - hoursInSeconds) / 60)
        let minutesInSeconds = minutes * 60

        let seconds = floor((stopWatchTime - hoursInSeconds -  minutesInSeconds) / 60)
        let secondsInCentiseconds = seconds * 100

        let centiseconds = stopWatchTime - hoursInSeconds - minutesInSeconds - secondsInCentiseconds

        let hoursLabel = String(format: "%02.0f:", hours)
        let minutesLabel = String(format: "%02.0f:", minutes)
        let secondsLabel = String(format: "%02.0f:", seconds)
        let centisecondsLabel = String(format: "%02.0f", centiseconds)

        counterLabel.text = hoursLabel + minutesLabel + secondsLabel + centiseconds

        stopWatchTime = stopWatchTime + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add Label to the variable `centiseconds`,as it is not string and `centisecondsLabel` is a `String`.That is why you got the binary operator error.
Use the below code:

```
 counterLabel.text = hoursLabel + minutesLabel + secondsLabel + centisecondsLabel
```

that will fix the problem!